# Программа питон на сайте

Tags: python, веб-программирование

В программировании новичок, написал мини программку используя pygame и созрел вопрос, как мне эту программку закинуть на мой веб-сайт(я представляю как нажимаю на текст "Игра" и открывается окно пайгейма). Буду признателен если объясните что для этого нужно или скиньте ссылочку на источники.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - а свой веб-сайт вы уже сделали? Понимаете, как он работает, какие у него есть страницы, как организованы переходы между страницами? Понимаете, что и как происходит, когда вы "нажимаете на текст "Игра"?

Comment: задача сделать не сайт а именно сделать возможность открывать програмку через сайт. а как сделать это и что для этого нужно в интернете не могу найти